# Can website visitors see server-side source code?

Tags: php, encode

I want to make sure visitors to my site can't see the PHP code that's generating the page. Here is a reference: http://may.edu.np/tmp/

Can anyone explain to me how server-side scripts are interpreted and how the result is delivered to the end user?

Comment: There's no sign of any PHP near that URL.

Comment: php is executed on server-side and client receives only HTML, CSS and JS content

Comment: **A:** PHP "source code" can NOT be seen once it has been parsed and will only output rendered as HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, no one should be able to access your source code so long as they don't have access to the server. When a browser makes a request for a .php file to the server, the server knows that it must first interpret the script and then send the output from your `echo` statements and/or inline HTML. As far as I know, there's no way for the user to "trick" the server into sending it as plain text, so I wouldn't worry about that. Also, as long as you disable error reporting, no one should even know you're running php, as there's no ".php" in the URL. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow

Comment: @akshaykhale Thank you! I really don't know what I'm doing in terms of answering questions so I hope this isn't complete garbage, but I have been working in like seven different languages for about four years now so I figured it was time to try to help people (especially considering how much I learned from this site).

Comment: Why did this answer give me +10 reputation? How does this whole thing work? Sorry if this is not the right place to ask this question.

Comment: @HawkensVonShriek because, someone agreed with your answer and gave you "positive rep" ;-) as did I.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Awesome! I suppose I could've just read the "What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?" thing, as I am now, but thank you for the fast and helpful response.

Comment: @HawkensVonShriek, when you receive upvote on your answer you will get 10 Rep. points and if ans. got accepted you will get 15 upvotes. for each question upvote you will gain 5 rep. points thats why 20 for 2 ans. upvotes read more here http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation